# Factorising a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I have read many questions on this website earlier regarding factorization of a determinant but i have one small doubt that has been troubling me a lot. For example if you had to factorize this determinant

\begin{vmatrix}
x&y&z\\
x^2&y^2&z^2\\
x^3&y^3&z^3\\
\end{vmatrix}

I understood that if x=y the determinant evaluates to 0 and therefore by factor theorem $x-y$ is a factor. However when we put y=x then we also get the determinant as 0 so shouldn't $y-x$ also be a factor thereby making $(x-y)^2$ as a factor of the determinant?

Comment: This is a variant of the famous Vandermonde determinant.

Comment: For your question, no.... because $y-x$ and $x-y$ aren't coprime.

Comment: Oh I see. Could you please give me an example where $(x-y)^2$ is a factor of the determinant so that i get a more clear picture.

Comment: I'm afraid by your method i.e. "x is the root of the det so x-y is a factor" you wouldn't be able to conclude the existence of any higher order factor.

Comment: Instead of phrasing it as "*by setting $x$ equal to $y$ we see.... and setting $y$ equal to $x$ we also see....*"  both of these two steps can be phrased in the same way as "*supposing that $x$ and $y$ happened to be equal, we notice that...*"  so your two observations were in fact the *same* observation, not different ones.

Comment: @physics123 \begin{vmatrix}
1& 1& 0& 0\\
x& y& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 1& 1\\
0& 0& x& y\\
\end{vmatrix}
The determinant is $(x-y)^2$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to factorise your determinant. By your approach, you should be able to see why $x,y,z,x-y,y-z,x-z$ must all be its factors. So the det must have 
$$xyz(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)$$
as a factor. So we have 
$$\det A=f(x,y,z)xyz(x-y)(y-z)(x-z)$$
Now if $f$ viewed as a polynomial in $x$ has $\deg_x f>0$, then $\det A$ viewed as a polynomial in $x$ would have degree greater than or equal to $4$, which is impossible. Same for $y,z$, so $f$ must be constant. To determine its value, again we view $\det A$ as a polynomial in $x$, what should be its leading coefficient?

As a caveat: this particular method works only for particular determinants, because it can only find the linear factors of the determinant, but in general the factors of a determinant aren't all necessarily linear, of course.

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks nice catch